# Laravel password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, hash

I have question if you want: 
- Why password hash `bcrypt` in laravel is random `unlike` sha1?

I test `password 12345678`in bcrypt and the result are different or with `sha1` the same result.

- So, how the system recognize password bcrypt in login app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's just how `bcrypt()` and `Hash::make` work. Every time you run the method, you get a different string.

To check if password is correct, Laravel uses `Hash::check()` method:

```
Hash::check($passord, $hashedPassword)
```

> Verifying A Password Against A Hash
>
> The check method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash.

Under the hood this method uses [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) PHP function.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing#basic-usage

Comment: In my DatabaseSeeder I use Hash::make('admin1234') and I store other password admin1234 and I check. It's OK.
But in my input with password admin12345, the connexion is passed.
Where is the problem

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON I don't see your code, so I can't tell where is the problem exactly.

Comment: see the last answer @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON you don't need to use `check()` method if you already use `attempt()`. Also, when you use `attempt()`, pass not hashed password `Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])`.

Comment: return false with password not hashed

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON well, as you've said you're trying to enter wrong password, that's why you get `false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162651/discussion-between-tojo-rodialson-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: yes I use wrong password for test but now I use correct password but return false

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON make sure you've used `bcrypt()` when generated and saved the password to DB for that user. Also, make sure you're passing correct not hashed password to the method and not an empty string or `null`.

Comment: with print_r can display this method Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]